# Neo4j python Driver March 08 Release: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neo4j'

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, driver

I just installed the newest (08-03-2019) Neo4j package through the command `pip install neo4j`.

and I'm getting this error:

> Unable to import 'neo4j'pylint(import-error)

I checked all the installed packages: ['astroid', 'certifi', 'chardet', 'colorama', 'googlemaps', 'idna', 'isort', 'lazy-object-proxy', 'mccabe', **'neo4j'**, 'neobolt', 'neotime', 'pylint', 'pyodbc', 'pytz', 'requests', 'six', 'typed-ast', 'urllib3', 'wrapt']

I'm using Python version 3.6.8, in Visual Studio Code.

I changed the Visual Studio Code settings to get the right Python Path. Re-installed pylint, and same mistake.
All other packages are OK.